# Is it possible to set expiration for a Web Api response in an ActionFilterAttribute?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to set expiration for some of my Web Api responses to encourage caching for data which changes very infrequently. To that end, I have created an ActionFilterAttribute thus:

```
public class ClientCacheFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
        var expiry = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddMonths(1).ToString("R");
        actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Expires", expiry);
    }
}
```

... and I've also tried this:

```
public class ClientCacheFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
        actionExecutedContext.Response.Content.Headers.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddMonths(1);
    }
}
```

... and attach it as appropriate to controller methods:

```
public class MyDataController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ClientCacheFilter]
    public List<MyObject> GetMyData()
    {
         return /* the data I want to return */
    }
}
```

When I examine the response, I see that the Expires header has the value -1. It seems that I can't set the expiry I want on the response header. I've run under debug so I know the action filter method is being executed. What am I overlooking or doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4):

You also need to set the CacheControl header:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetMyData()
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myData);
    response.Content.Headers.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddMonths(1);
    // without this the Expires header won't be set!
    response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue();
    return ResponseMessage(response);
}
```

Alternatively, instead of setting the Expires header you may set the max-age directive in CacheControl:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetMyData()
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myData);
    response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue
    {
        Public = true,
        MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(30)
    };

    return ResponseMessage(response);
}
```